# How to use iterator to retrieve objects from two classes in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, iterator

I am new to Java and learning about collections. I have a problem in retrieving data using an `Iterator` from two class objects, I am only able to get output for any single class but not two classes.

This is my code:

```
package ncl;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;


public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Market m1 = new Market(1234, "Suryam", 1200.10);
    Market m2 = new Market(4321, "SWathi", 1200.10);
    Market m3 = new Market(1111, "Chinna", 1200.10);
    Market m4 = new Market(2222, "Malli Bava", 1200.10);
    Market m5 = new Market(3333, "Vali", 1200.10);

    RetailShop rt1 = new RetailShop("Swathi", 8121720217l, 500087);
    RetailShop rt2 = new RetailShop("Tumbu", 9989330442l, 500087);
    RetailShop rt3 = new RetailShop("Suri Babu", 9010627821l, 500087);

    ArrayList<Object> al = new ArrayList<Object>();

    // Adding Market
    al.add(m1);
    al.add(m2);
    al.add(m3);
    al.add(m4);
    al.add(m5);

    // Adding RetailShop
    al.add(rt1);
    al.add(rt2);
    al.add(rt3);

    Iterator itr = al.iterator();

    while(itr.hasNext())
    {
        Market mt=(Market)itr.next();

            System.out.println(mt.billamount);
            System.out.println(mt.customer);
            System.out.println(mt.invoiceno);

        RetailShop rts=(RetailShop)itr.next();
        System.out.println(rts.custName);
    }
}
}
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here? I want to print `Market` data along with `RetailShop` data

Comment: Maybe you can wrap the cast to `Market` in a try/catch since it will throw `ClassCastException` if it fails. Once such exception is caught you can try to cast to `RetailShop` and print the relevant information.

Comment: You're trying to read `Market` and `RetailShop` alternately. But they're not in your list alternately. They're `M,M,M,M,M,R,R,R`

Comment: Avoid mixing things inside an `ArrayList`.Create an `ArrayList<Market>` and an `ArrayList<RetailShop>` , and iterate over those collections with their own iterators (two distinct loops) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, ArrayList with object is bad practice, prefer to use this

```
List<Market> a1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<RetailShop> a2 = new ArrayList<>();

//Adding Market
al.add(m1);
al.add(m2);
al.add(m3);
al.add(m4);
al.add(m5);
//Adding RetailShop

a2.add(rt1);
a2.add(rt2);
a3.add(rt3);

for(Market mt:a1){
   System.out.println(mt.billamount);
   System.out.println(mt.customer);
   System.out.println(mt.invoiceno);
}
for(RetailShop rts:a2){
   System.out.println(rts.custName);
}
```

If you want to use one list, then you indeed need to cast, but you should check the cast like so:

```
while(itr.hasNext())
{
    Object o = itr.next();
    if(o instanceof Market){
        Market mt = (Market) o;
        System.out.println(mt.billamount);
        System.out.println(mt.customer);
        System.out.println(mt.invoiceno);
    }else if(o instanceof RetailShop){
        RetailShop rts=(RetailShop) o;
        System.out.println(rts.custName);
    }

}
```

What this does is it checks the class of each element in the list. If it's a market, it'll cast the object to a market and do the relevant code for it. And the came for the retailshop.

Comment: could you please show how to retrive data with  List<Market> a1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<RetailShop> a2 = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: You made it little easy though +1 @Thijs Steel, Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Use `instanceof` operator to check which type of object is there in your List

```
Iterator itr = al.iterator();

    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        Object o = itr.next();
        if (o instanceof Market) {
            Market mt = (Market) o;
            System.out.println(mt.billamount);
            System.out.println(mt.customer);
            System.out.println(mt.invoiceno);
        }

        if (o instanceof RetailShop) {
            RetailShop rts = (RetailShop)o;
            System.out.println(rts.custName);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have a different objects (Market and RetailShop) in the same ArrayList, you should first check before casting the object if it is the correct (right) object. For example to cast object to Market you should make sure that this object is Market.

```
Iterator itr=al.iterator();

while(itr.hasNext())
{
Object obj=itr.next();
if (obj instanceof Market){
    Market mt=(Market)obj;
    System.out.println(mt.billamount);
    System.out.println(mt.customer);
    System.out.println(mt.invoiceno);
    } 
else {
     if(obj instanceof RetailShop)
      {
      RetailShop rts=(RetailShop)obj;
      System.out.println(rts.custName);
      }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

since your list is holding Objects you need to 1st check the type before doing a cast conversion

```
  List<Object> l = Arrays.asList(1, null, 3, "Hello", 5, null);

    Iterator<Object> it = l.iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Object x = (Object) it.next();

        if (x != null) {
            System.out.println("getClass: " + x.getClass());
            if ("integer".equalsIgnoreCase(x.getClass().getSimpleName())) {
                System.out.println("This is an int: " + (Integer) x);
            } else if ("string".equalsIgnoreCase(x.getClass().getSimpleName())) {
                System.out.println("This is a string: " + (String) x);
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("the element is null");
        }
    }
```